# INTran Not showing LotNumberNbr

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I have made a new Grid to show data from INTran(PX.Objects.IN.INTran)
I see there is a LotSerialNbr in the INTran DAC. But when I make a new PXSelect I don't see it in the "ADD DATA FIELDS" on my page. 
I add the Lot/Serial Nbr(LotSerialNbr) when loading stock on the Inventory Receipts.

I have also checked INRegister and INTranSplit  both not show the Lot Serial Nbr?

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.SO;

namespace Test
{
    public class StockTransfer : PXGraph<StockTransfer>
    {

        public PXSave<MasterTable> Save;
        public PXCancel<MasterTable> Cancel;


        public PXFilter<MasterTable > MasterView;
        public PXFilter<INTran> DetailsView;

        [Serializable]
        public class MasterTable : IBqlTable
        {

        }

        [Serializable]
        public class DetailsTable : IBqlTable
        {

        }

        public PXSelect<INRegister> Register;
        public PXSelect<INTran> INTran;
        public PXSelect<INTranSplit > INTranSplit  ;
    }
}
```

How can I get the Lot Serial number to show on the grid?

edit here is the ASPX:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="ABIT1111.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_ABIT1111" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormDetail.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="JVDLocationTransfer.TransferGrap"
        PrimaryView="MasterView"
        >
    <CallbackCommands>

    </CallbackCommands>
  </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="MasterView" Width="100%" Height="100px" AllowAutoHide="false">
    <Template>
      <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule1" runat="server" StartRow="True"></px:PXLayoutRule>
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit1" DataField="UsrFROMLocation" />
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit2" DataField="UsrInventoryID" />
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit3" DataField="UsrInventoryItemDescription" />
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit4" DataField="UsrQty" />
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit5" DataField="UsrReasonCode" />
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit6" DataField="UsrSKU" />
      <px:PXTextEdit runat="server" ID="CstPXTextEdit7" DataField="UsrUOM" /></Template>
  </px:PXFormView>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont3" ContentPlaceHolderID="phG" Runat="Server">
  <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Details" AllowAutoHide="false">
    <Levels>
      <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="INTran">
          <Columns>
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID" Width="70" />
        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LotSerialNbr" ></px:PXGridColumn></Columns>
      </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
    <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
    <ActionBar >
    </ActionBar>
  </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: ASPX is missing from your question. LotSerialNbr is in INTran and INTranSplit DACs, if it's not showing there's an error in your solution or it wasn't recompiled (published) before opening the customization project.

Comment: Hi HB I have added the ASPX

Answer (score 0):

The screen graph `JVDLocationTransfer.TransferGrap` declared in ASPX doesn't match the target `StockTransfer` graph. Also inexistent columns are declared on dataview like `MasterView` which points to empty DACs like `MasterTable`. Wizards functionality such as Add Data Field won't work properly in that context.